# Event on class with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, addeventlistener

I'm trying to implement a remove function inside the fullcalendar jquery to do such thing I need to access elements inside my events. That's why I added de fc-task-delete.

```
<div class="fc-event-container">
<a class="fc-time-grid-event fc-v-event fc-event fc-start fc-end fc-draggable fc-resizable" style="top: 373px; bottom: -461px; z-index: 1; left: 0%; right: 0%;">
    <div class="fc-content">
        <div class="fc-task-delete" style="text-align:right; color:red"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></div>
        <div class="fc-time" data-start="08:30" data-full="08:30 - 10:30"><span>08:30 - 10:30</span></div>
        <div class="fc-title">Un event test</div><div class="fc-description">This event could have been in database</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Js side, I tried this, but it's not working the call is never done.

```
var deleted=document.getElementsByClassName('glyphicon-remove');
for (var i = 0; i < deleted.length; i++) {
    deleted[i].addEventListener('click', test);
}

function test(){
    console.log("clic remove");
}
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (except the inline css :p); I don't even know if the issue comes from fullcalendar or my code. 
Thanks for your help.

PS: For more info, this event is launched on my tasks, but the glyphicon is inside the dom using this event, so I have to somehow detect when I am exactly hover the cross and not only over the task to do differents things if I want to delete or update.

```
    eventClick: function(event, element) {
        var title_modified = prompt('Event Title:');
        var desc_modified = prompt('Event Description:');
        var eventData;
        if (title_modified) {
          event.title=title_modified;
          event.description=desc_modified;
          $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event); // stick? = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Since events are loaded into the calendar (and then rendered) asynchronously, this could be the cause of your problem - the elements concerned maybe don't actually exist when you try to bind an event to them. Try using jQuery delegated event syntax e.g. `$("#calendar").on("click", ".glyphicon-remove", function(e) {` etc

Comment: Indeed, I fixed the issue by delaying the addlistenner into setTimeout...it's a little bit ugly but it works

Comment: That's very ugly and not reliable if the async operation takes longer than normal. Delegated events would be a better solution

Comment: You're right nothing more to say. I didn't know "delegated events" so I fixed the only way I knew. Eventualy I will modify.

Comment: For more info see http://api.jquery.com/on/ and read the section "Direct and delegated events", it's a useful technique to deal with cases where the elements you want to handle events on don't exist yet, but may be loaded into the page at some future time.